# How to create a PrtSc (print screen) shortcut for Lightshot in Linux Mint

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I use Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit. I have `xdotool` installed.

**Lightshot** is running since login, always, I used Startup Applications tool to create a start-up immediately after login:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/vlastimil/.lightshot" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/vlastimil/.lightshot/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Lightshot/Lightshot.lnk
```

---

Goal:

To press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> (print screen key) and enter full-screen cutting mode (de facto, the same functionality Lightshot has under Windows).

---

What works (when run from `gnome-terminal`):

```
xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --limit 1 --all --pid $(pgrep Lightshot) --name Lightshot) "Print"
```

---

However, it does not do anything, if that is copy-pasted into the *Add custom* shortcut dialog:

[image: Add custom shortcut dialog]

I merely wonder why that is and, more importantly, how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2020-Jan-02

You can find the [latest revision](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/lightshot-print-screen-linux-handler/releases/latest) and [usage instructions](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/lightshot-print-screen-linux-handler#usage-instructions) on [its GitHub page](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/lightshot-print-screen-linux-handler).

---

#### Original post

The reason probably is, that I haven't specified any shell to be run into, and so the following works:

```
sh -c 'xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --limit 1 --all --pid $(pgrep Lightshot) --name Lightshot) "Print"'
```

---

**EDIT:**

It might be noteworthy, that I decided to write a script for it now. Fully validating every step:

```
#!/bin/sh

is_number()
{
    # check if exactly one argument has been passed
    test "$#" -eq 1 || print_error_and_exit 5 "is_number(): There has not been passed exactly one argument!"

    # check if the argument is an integer
    test "$1" -eq "$1" 2>/dev/null
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

print_error_and_exit()
{
    # check if exactly two arguments have been passed
    test "$#" -eq 2 || print_error_and_exit 3 "print_error_and_exit(): There have not been passed exactly two arguments!"

    # check if the first argument is a number
    is_number "$1" || print_error_and_exit 4 "print_error_and_exit(): The argument #1 is not a number!"

    # check if we have color support
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        bold=$(tput bold)
        red=$(tput setaf 1)
        nocolor=$(tput sgr0)
        echo "$bold$red$2 Exit code = $1.$nocolor" 1>&2
    else
        echo "$2 Exit code = $1." 1>&2
    fi

    exit "$1"
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

check_for_prerequisite()
{
    # check if exactly one argument has been passed
    test "$#" -eq 1 || print_error_and_exit 2 "check_for_prerequisite(): There has not been passed exactly one argument!"

    # check if the argument is a program which is installed
    command -v "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || print_error_and_exit 6 "check_for_prerequisite(): I require $1 but it's not installed :-("
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# check if no arguments have been passed to the script
test "$#" -gt 0 && print_error_and_exit 1 "$0: You have passed some unexpected argument(s) to the script!"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# check for prerequisites
check_for_prerequisite "pgrep"
check_for_prerequisite "xdotool"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# global constants
lightshot_key="Print"
lightshot_name="Lightshot"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# get the lightshot pid
lightshot_pid=$(pgrep "$lightshot_name")

# test if a pid has been successfully acquired
is_number "$lightshot_pid" || print_error_and_exit 7 "lightshot_pid: The argument is not a number!\\nLightshot is most probably not running."

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# get the window id from lightshot pid
lightshot_wnd=$(xdotool search --limit 1 --all --pid "$lightshot_pid" --name "$lightshot_name")

# test if a window handler has been successfully acquired
is_number "$lightshot_wnd" || print_error_and_exit 8 "lightshot_wnd: The argument is not a number!\\nLightshot is most probably not running."

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# simulate a print screen key press on the lightshot window
xdotool key --window "$lightshot_wnd" "$lightshot_key"
```